# Application close in background while opening activity having dialog (style Theme.Dialog)

Tags: android

Issue: Whenever I click About button, About activity open in the dialog box as I add Theme.Dialog style in AndroidManifest.xml, but in the background, application closed and after side click of dialog box it disappeared and then I want MainActivity (Sudoku activity) in the background or like remain open in the background of the dialog box.
You can easily resolve it on the webpage itself: https://github.com/liveHarshit/Sudoku/issues/1  and create a pull request.

AndroidManifest.xml code (Sudoku is MainActivity ) -

```
<activity android:name=".About"
            android:label="@string/about_title"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog"
            android:parentActivityName=".Sudoku">
        </activity>
```

MainActivity Sudoku code -

```
Button about = (Button)findViewById(R.id.about_button);

        about.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent about_activity = new Intent(Sudoku.this,About.class);
                startActivity(about_activity);
                finish();
            }
        });
```

Layout code -

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:padding="10dp">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/about_content"
        android:text="@string/about_text"/>

</ScrollView>
```

Java class code -

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class About extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_about);
    }

}
```

Comment: If you don't want `MainActivity` to finish, don't call `finish();`.

Comment: remove `finish()` at `onclick`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `android:parentActivityName=".Sudoku"` is **Sudoku** as you have declared in **Manifest.xml** so stop calling

`finish();`

to allow the background to keep showing..

```
Button about = (Button)findViewById(R.id.about_button);

    about.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent about_activity = new Intent(Sudoku.this,About.class);
            startActivity(about_activity);
           // finish(); remove this finish
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

In you `MainActivity` you will have to remove `finish()` after starting `About` Activity:

```
Button about = (Button)findViewById(R.id.about_button);

    about.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent about_activity = new Intent(Sudoku.this,About.class);
            startActivity(about_activity);
        }
    });
```